# How to parse CSV file and store it's data into database?

Tags: javascript, php, html, csv

I trying to store CSV data to database using onclick function. Unfortunately, I am using php code inside javascript function which is not efficient enough. Therefore, I hope that I can get any suggest or solution to improve efficiency of my project by using javascript instead of php to store CSV data into database.

This is javascript with php code :

```
<script>
function storeQueEmail(){
<?php    
    $file = $_FILES[csv][tmp_name]; 
    $handle = fopen($file,"r"); 

    //loop through the csv file and insert into database 
    do { 
        if ($data[0]) { 
            $record['contact_first'] = $data[0];
            $record['contact_last'] = $data[1];
            $record['contact_email'] = $data[2];
            $record['subject'] = $_REQUEST['subject'];
            $record['message'] = $_REQUEST['message'];
            $record['status'] = 0;

            $oAdminEmail->insertQueEmail($record);
            } 
    } while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'")); 

    ?>  
    }
</script>
```

This is HTML code :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" /> 
<title>Import a CSV File with PHP & MySQL</title> 
</head> 
<body> 
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1" > 
  Subject : <br/>
  <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" required/> <br/>
  Choose your upload type: <br /> 
    <input name="csv" type="file" id="csv" accept=".csv" required/> <br/>
  Content : <br/>
  <textarea name="message" cols="50" rows="10" required></textarea><br/>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="storeQueEmail()"/> 
</form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: You can read the contents of a CSV in JavaScript and then HTTp post via Ajax. I wrote a similar answer to a different question that includes a demo of reading the CSV client side: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22518786/js-get-method-file-with-path/22520019#22520019

Comment: What I trying to do is store CSV file into database. Is it possible to provide me a sample code on how its work? Because I am still new in javascript.

Comment: Did you say you are using PHP code INSIDE of a JavaScript function? Is that even possible?

Comment: This function work perfect but when I try to add in another javascript function and it will cause other function cannot work.

Answer (score 0):

what are you trying to do there? I think you are speaking about a PHP in
HTML document. So your PHP code inside your function is interpreted on server. As your PHP code has no output your Javascript function is simply empty. Thus as you have registered your Javascript function as onclick handler just nothing would happen.

Remember that standard Javascript code is interpreted on Client (that means in browser) though  you PHP code is interpreted on server. As mentioned in the comments above it is possible to use an AJAX or POST/GET - Request to send data to your server and then write it to your DB or file etc.

Another way to do this directly with Javascript is Node.js - serverside Javascript that is able to write to your Database like PHP can do.

The easiest way for you to do it with your HTML code you presented above is to fill in your

```
action - attribute
```

in your

```
form tag
```

For example:

```
<form action="proccessData.php" ...>
...
</form>
```

Don't forget to remove your onclick - attribute inside form's submit input field.
If you know press your submit button your entire form and its content will be send to http://www.xyz.de/proccessData.php. Inside that file you can work with your form data: In your case two text fields and one file upload field. As you may know you could get to the content of text input field send via post via:

```
$_POST['<name of field>']
```

To get your uploaded file and proccess it you could use PHP's global

```
$_FILE[] - Array
```

Just refer to PHP's manual on php.net or some other online documentation. There's pretty much to find on the web.
I just give you a helpful link to php.net on how to handle file uploads in a correct and therefor secure manner: https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Once you have read your uploaded file via PHP's global $_FILE[] - array just proccess that file via fgetcsv in your proccessData.php and write it line for line to your database.

Hope that helps! It is really not that hard :)

Comment: thanks for reply bro. is it possible to provide me an example code on it?

Comment: Just improved my answer with some explanations on one way how to do it. If you develop web applications always make a clear difference in your mind between code thats executed on client and code thats executed server side. In my point of view thats one of the most important steps to really understand whats going on.

Comment: actually I want to validate my csv file in same page which do not pass value to a new page. refresh page is not flexible enough. your way to do is efficient and i know how to do it. but what i want is do everything within one page. thanks.

Comment: Hi! Just use Javascript to to validation before you send your from to server: You could use the onsubmit - Attribute inside your form - Element and inside the function you passed you could do validation. If you delete your action - attribute you then can send your form data to your server via AJAX. At the end of that function you could then display a msg or sth. else via DOM manipulation. I would recommend to use JQuery to do that cause it is very simply to send data asynchron to server as well to manipulate the document structure. There is plenty of information on the web on how to do it.:)